# Which issues, if any, are the Hellboy movies based on?

Tags: comics, suggested-order, hellboy

I was wondering which comic issues cover the story arcs used for the two live-action films. Supposing, of course, that the films were adaptations of existing comics, and not original plots loosely connected to comics.

And, if they are based on specific issues, what's the order to read them in? (Numerical seems logical, but I don't know if a golden army storyline would have  happened before or after the stuff in the first film.)

If there are collections/anthologies, I'd prefer those over a large list of individual issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hellboy 2: The Golden Army* is pretty much original, while *Hellboy* taken inspiration from several comics.

Hellboy's film origin is similar to the comic version shown in *Seed of Destruction*. The main difference being that in the film, the Nazi and English parties meet in the same church, while in the comic, they operate in completely different areas and never interact.

[image]

[image]

The film also takes the trek to Heisenvald Ridge to resurrect Rasputin,

> the professor's death, Liz losing control of her powers in the climax

and several other details from from *Seed of Destruction*.

The skeleton that guides Hellboy was likely inspired by Giurescu, who served the same function in the comic *Wake the Devil*.

[image]

[image]

In the film, Hellboy

> regrows, and then breaks off, his horns,

something he is first shown doing in *Wake the Devil*.

Hellboy wears the Crown of Apocalypse in a vision. It's first shown in the comic *Box Full of Evil*. The film has almost an exact panel recreation from that comic.

[image]

[image]

The "key to the bottomless pit" scene is inspired by the comic *Wake the Devil*.

[image]

> Rasputin: "And I looked and beheld an Angel, and in his hand the key to the bottomless pit..."
>
> Ilsa [to Hellboy]: You are the key! The right hand of doom!

*Hellboy* 2019 takes influence from a few. It begins with Hellboy in Mexico, similar to *Hellboy in Mexico*. Most notably, they both show
Hellboy fighting in a luchedor match with his bat-corrupted friend and and eventually stabbing them through the ring.

[image]

[image]

It takes its main plot from *Darkness Calls*, *The Wild Hunt*, and *The Storm and the Fury*, which served as a sort of three-part story in the comics. Elements taken include Nimue as the main villain, Alice as Hellboy's ally, and the Osiris Club scenes.

A few elements come from other stories, most significantly Ben Daimio who actually comes from the *B.P.R.D.* series and never met Hellboy in the comics.

The animated *Hellboy: Sword of Storms* takes some scenes from various Hellboy short stories set in Japan. Its sequel *Hellboy: Blood and Iron* is partially based on *Hellboy: Wake the Devil*, with both concerning vampires and Hecate.

Comment: Are these individual comics you mentioned part of a particular arc, or are they widely spread through the various runs?

Comment: @creationedge They're the first several volumes, but they aren't othetwise related.

Answer (score 4):

The Hellboy movies are only loosely based on the comics.

The comics themselves don't always follow a clear order. Here's a nice [guide](http://thunderpeel2001.blogspot.com.au/2008/11/hellboy-reading-order.html) to reading them that I found online.

As far as I can tell, The movies only incorporate ideas from Seed of Destruction.